# firestore array: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Tags: flutter

I want to take 'url' from 'firestore' and convert this url to photo

```
    The following _TypeError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<DocumentSnapshot>#0bb1f):
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot> file:///C:/Users/***/AndroidStudioProjects/deneme_sinavi/lib/sinav_screen.dart:47:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _MyHomePageState.function.<anonymous closure> (package:deneme_sinavi/sinav_screen.dart:84:32)
#1      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:403:8)
#2      _MyHomePageState.function (package:deneme_sinavi/sinav_screen.dart:83:17)
#3      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:deneme_sinavi/sinav_screen.dart:65:19)
#4      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:777:55)
...
```

I want to show this with a 'futurebuilder' and 'network.image'.

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        future: sinavlar.doc(widget.docID).get(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Something went wrong");
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
            if (data != null){
              List list = data["link"];
              return PageView(
                    controller: PageController(
                        initialPage: 0
                    ),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    children: [
                  function(list)
                    ]
                );
            }else{
              return Text("");
            }
          }
           return Text("");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  function(List list){
    return list.forEach((element) {
            Image.network(list[element]);
    });
  }
```

I deleted the articles in print to publish

Could this be because the name of the array list is link

Comment: instead of `Image.network(list[element]);`, call `Image.network(element);` directly

Comment: you should use map instead of forEach as return type of forEach is void.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it happened

```
return PageView(
                controller: PageController(
                    initialPage: 0
                ),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                children: function(list)

            );
```

and this

```
function(List list){

    List<Widget> list2 = [];

    print(list);
    for (var i in list){
      print(Image.network(i));
      list2.add(Image.network(i));
    }
    print(list2);
    return list2;



  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things has to be fixed:

```
PageView(
    controller: PageController(
        initialPage: 0
    ),
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: function(list)  
);
```

and

```
List<String> function(List list){
    return list.map<String>((element) {
            return Image.network(element);
    },
);
```